# Create a curl url in bash

Tags: bash

I need to have curl url formatted like this in order for it to be successful.

```
$instanceUrl/sobjects/$sObject/describe -H 'Authorization: Bearer $apiToken'
```

This is my script so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
CURL='/usr/bin/curl'
CURLARGS='-H'

echo "welcome to sf-db-mock"

echo "please enter the instance url of the Salesforce org database you'd like to mock, followed by [ENTER]:"

# get rest endpoint
read instanceUrl

echo "please enter your api token, followed by [ENTER]:"

# get api token from users current session
read apiToken

# get the objects the users wants described
echo "please enter each sObject you'd like to mock by entering its API Name, using a space after each sObject, followed by [ENTER]:"

read -a sObjects

for sObject in ${sObjects[@]}

do
  describe="$('sobjects'\/$sObject\/'describe '$CURLARGS ' Authorization: Bearer '$apiToken)"
  echo $instanceUrl$describe
done
```

The error I get while running it is

> ./mock.txt: line 25: sobjects/survey/describe -H: No such file or directory'

My bash script is executable.

Answer (score 0):

The notation `$(a b c)` means run command `a` with arguments `b` and `c`.

What you want is to remove the parenthesis:

```
 describe="sobjects/$sObject/describe $CURLARGS 'Authorization: Bearer '$apiToken'"
```